# Calling two stored procedures in mysqli causes 'Commands out of sync' error

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli

**Problem Context**

I'm relatively new to most of the languages I'm working in, and I am gradually going back and improving old code. I'm re-writing some old PHP and replacing hardcoded SQL queries (*I know*) with calls to stored procedures.

The code in my pages is organised in the following order -

```
$RESULT_one = $connection->query( ... my first query ... ); 
$RESULT_two = $connection->query( ... my second query ... );

if(isset($RESULT_one) & isset($RESULT_two))
{
    // Generate a form using the results from the queries 
    // Loop through $RESULT_one to populate a combo box 
    $RESULT_one->free(); 
    // Loop through $RESULT_two to populate a combo box 
    $RESULT_two->free(); 
}
else 
{
    // Display an error to the user rather than displaying the form 
}
```

**Problem**

After replacing my first query and my second query with `CALL`s to stored procedures, I receive the error `#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`.

**Steps taken to attempt to solve the problem**

- [This poster on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745075/php-mysql-error-when-calling-multiple-stored-procedures) was having a similar problem and the accepted answer suggests calling `next_result()` which solves their issue. *However*, I want to check that both calls to the database were successful before generating my form, I do not want to half-generate it, as it were.
- I see [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150951/stored-procedure-causing-problems-with-mysqli-when-used-with-fetch-all) where the asker was having the same issue, and it seems that `next_result()` is unavoidable because "this is how mysqli works" - why does this work with 'raw' SQL but not with stored procedures? What is the difference? Is there an efficient way to check both queries were successful before generating my form? I'd like to understand what is going on and why the change in behavior.
- I stumbled across [documentation for `mysqli_store_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php) which seems like something which may potentially be useful. I've been reading the comments for this documentation but it isn't at all clear.
- It seems [the solution is to call `next_result()` on the mysqli object between calls](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#102904), as I learned from [this Stack Overflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997601/php-commands-out-of-sync-if-i-mysqliquery-again-after-a-call-to-a-results?rq=1)

Comment: I think because a procedure can request some time to run. The second procedure logically cannot run on the same time with the same db connection. Maybe if you start two different connection you can avoid the problem

Comment: Ah, right. So a stored procedure can request time to run which a statement does not do? Opening a couple of connections seems rather messy... (Unless my assumptions are mistaken) Is there a better way?

Comment: maybe waiting that the first procedure stopped running? Remember, a stteament processing is controlled by server side programming, a stored procedure (i see this with java/oracle) is commanded by db.

Answer (score 2):

When calling multiple stored procedures, the error `Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now` can occur unless steps are taken to prevent it.

One way is to call `next_result()` on the mysqli object after each stored procedure call, [as described here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#102904).

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this error in both phpmyadmin and running queries within php and simply calling next_result() as suggested didn't work for me. Coming from MS-SQL to MariaDB, I needed to alter my stored procedures to avoid using straight "SELECT" queries to populate variables and instead use "SELECT ... INTO" queries. Normal SELECT statements echo the selected data to the caller in a separate result set. I believe you then need to call "next_result" once for *each* SELECT statement that was executed in your stored procedure before you can call a new procedure. "SELECT ... INTO" doesn't echo any data which greatly improved speed and avoided this error.